# Inner product of two vectors expressed by different basis

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inner-products

How can I make sense on an inner product of two vectors expressed in different bases? For example, let $\mathbf {(a,b,c)}$ and $\mathbf {(a^*,b^*,c^*)}$ be two basis for the same three dimensional vector space $V$.

Now, let 
$$\mathbf v=v_1 \mathbf a+v_2\mathbf b+v_3\mathbf c,$$ 
and
$$\mathbf u=u_1 \mathbf a^*+u_2\mathbf b^*+u_3\mathbf c^*$$
be two vectors belonging to V.

What is the meaning of taking the following inner product:

$$\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf u = ?$$

**Update:**

Consider the case $\mathbf v, \mathbf u \in \mathbb Z^3$, how can I choose the second basis $\mathbf {(a^*,b^*,c^*)}$ such that, the product

$$\mathbf v \cdot \mathbf u = 2\pi n, \;\;\;\;\; n \in \mathbb Z$$

in some sense?

Comment: Look at the problem another way, you can choose the bases so that $v \cdot u$ has any value you want. So, unless there is a 'special relationship' between the bases, it is unlikely that the expression has meaning.

Comment: It makes sense because the choose of the second basis is my degree of freedom, while I need the inner product to be multiple of two pi.

Comment: Your question really needs more detail to help someone provide a useful answer.

Comment: I have updated the question. @Chappers

Comment: By [inner product]() we ordinarily requires a positive definite bilinear form on a vector space.  Defining the concept this way makes it independent of a choice of basis for the vector space, so the Question is unclear for that reason.  Also, you ask about $\mathbb{Z}^3$ in the Update, which is not a vector space.  Voting to close as unclear what you are asking.

Comment: @hardmath the question rises from the concept of reciprocal lattice, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_lattice. Perhaps I misunderstood what the basis lattice vectors are.

Comment: Perhaps a better phrase than "inner product" would be the "dot product" given by choosing an ordered basis (which does make sense for a lattice or $\mathbb{Z}$ module).  But now that the dot product depends on the choice of basis, it is unclear what you would like to achieve.

Comment: @hardmath I just wanted to understand how that product could make sense. However I did not ask it directly, and now I notice that the question is ill-formulated. 
Close it if you will, I cannot delete the question.

Comment: If there is a way to make your Question ask what you want to ask, I'm all for trying to answer it.  Since the coefficients of a linear combination of basis elements are integers, we cannot get an irrational value $2\pi n$ immediately from the dot product, but if you multipliy the dot product by a (real) constant, it might give you what you want.

Comment: @hardmath Okay, I will update it as soon as I can.

Answer (score 2):

The sum
$$
aa^* + bb^* + cc^*
$$
has no meaning since its value depends on the bases.

If you know how to express one of the bases in terms of the other you can compute the inner product of those two vectors. You will probably want the two bases to be orthonormal.